# Template Class With Variadic Constructor implemented in different ways: What are the benefits and downfalls of each version?

Tags: c++, performance, templates, variadic-functions

I have this template class written in two different ways: one uses a variadic constructor and the other uses `std::initializer_list<T>`. For the purpose of this question I will name the classe's differently, but mind you in my project it is the same class as both versions do the same thing. I would like to know what is the benefits and downfalls of both versions. Which one is more efficient and why?

**Variadic Version:**

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Nodes {
private:
    unsigned m_numParams;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> m_vNodes;

public:
    Nodes() : m_numParams(0), m_vNodes { nullptr } {}

    template <typename ... Ts >
    explicit Nodes( Ts&&...ts ) :
        m_numParams( sizeof...(Ts) ),
        m_vNodes{ std::make_shared<T>( std::forward<Ts>( ts ) )... }
    {}    
}; // Nodes

int main() {
     int x = 3;
     int y = 5;
     int z = 7;

     Nodes<int> nodes( x, y, z );

     return 0;
}
```

**`std::initializer_list<T>` version**

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
class Nodes2 {
private:
    unsigned m_numParams;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<T>> m_vNodes;

public:
    Nodes2() : m_numParams(0), m_vNodes{ nullptr } {}

    explicit Nodes2( std::initializer_list<T> ini ) :
        m_numParams( ini.size() ) {
        for ( auto&& e : ini ) {
            m_vNodes.push_back( std::make_shared<T>( e ) );
        }
    }

}; // Nodes2

int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = 3;
    int z = 3;

    std::initialize_list<int> ini{ x, y, z };
    Nodes2<int> nodes2( ini );

    return 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a generic container, and don't know the type of object which will be stored (`T`), and you want to allow move-construction, then the variadic version is better.

This is because you can't move from an `std::initializer_list`, so your 2nd version will have to copy construct the `T` object.

From [`cppreference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list):

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<T>` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`

There is no way to get mutable access to the stored array of objects.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I'm not familiar with `std::initializer_list` and I'm starting to learn different techniques that involve the use of templates with the use of variadic types. Your answer has provided me with some insight. When I originally was constructing this class; my first approach was using the variadic version in which I had to ask the community on how to properly construct it. At first they were suggesting that I use `std::initializer_list`, but for my purposes as this will be generic my initial approach is the appropriate one.

Comment: @FrancisCugler as an aside, in the code presented in your example, you could get rid of `m_numParams` and just use `m_vNodes.size()` directly - no need for the extra variable

Comment: I know; but it also makes it convenient to have it around instead of calling the .size() function; I can have the class to have its own size() function. That extra variable is not a big deal; and it keeps track of the size based on how many parameters are passed into the constructor automatically. As for now I was using it for debugging & testing purposes to make sure that the vector of shared pointers was being added correctly while constructing this class considering I'm learning how to work with variadic functions; variadic templates.